# Change object attribute in an array of objects with Ramda.js

Tags: node.js, ramda.js

I have an array of object like this:

```
[
  {type: 'x', 'attributes': {status: 'emitted', num: 1}}, 
  {type: 'y', attributes: {status: 'changed', num: 2}}
]
```

I want to change every status: emitted to 'done' and every status: 'changed' to 'error'

How can I do this with ramda?

Answer (score 1):

Create a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of statuses and their replacements, and a function to return the replacement (`updateStatus`) when given a value (`current`). Iterate the array with [R.map](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#map), and use [R.evolve](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#evolve) to create a new object with updated status.

```js
const status = new Map([['emitted', 'done'], ['changed', 'error']])

// get the current state replacement from the Map or use current if no replacement is available
const updateStatus = current => status.get(current) || current

const fn = R.map(R.evolve({
  attributes: {
    status: updateStatus
  }
}))

const data = [{type: 'x', 'attributes': {status: 'emitted', num: 1}}, { type: 'y', attributes: {status: 'changed', num: 2}}]

const result = fn(data)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To fully appreciate the API ramda provides, I think it's worth it to add the "plain" javascript alternative (If you're willing to use the [ECMAScript 2018 Object Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)).

In the function arguments, you destructure your object right up until the properties you'd like to modify. All others props are collected in a `...rest` parameter.

In the body of the map function, you recreate a new object, making the modifications to the properties you need.

As you can see, it can be quite hard to parse out the parts that are being changed. +1 to the ramda approach

```js
const entries = [ { type: 'x', 'attributes': {status: 'emitted', num: 1}}, { type: 'y', attributes: {status: 'changed', num: 2 } } ];

const statusMap = { "emitted": "done", "changed": "error" };

console.log(
  entries.map(
    ({ attributes: { status, ...ra }, ...re }) =>
    ({ attributes: { status: statusMap[status], ...ra }, ...re })
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { lensPath, map, over } from 'ramda'

const status = {emitted: 'done', changed: 'error'}
const updateStatus = current => status[current] ?? current
const statusLens = lensPath(['attributes', 'status']) 
const updateStatus = map(over(statusLens, updateStatus))
```

```js
updateStatus([
  {type: 'x', 'attributes': {status: 'emitted', num: 1}}, 
  {type: 'y', attributes: {status: 'changed', num: 2}}
])
// =>
// [
//   {type: 'x', 'attributes': {status: 'done', num: 1}}, 
//   {type: 'y', attributes: {status: 'error', num: 2}}
// ]
```